# python intra-package imports

Tags: python, django

i'm creating a django application inside a virtualenv. I have a directory structure like below:

```
/proj
  /apps
    /polls
  /config
  /lib
```

Currently, i'm using absolute imports everywhere, so for example if I wanted to load lib/utils.py from polls, i'd use 'from proj.lib import utils'.

This is a bit of a pain though because it seems I need to create a symlink in my site-packages directory to 'proj' so that it can resolve where proj points to. How can I make is so I don't need to create this symlink?

I was going to convert everything to use relative imports, but for some reason PEP008 discourages them. Why is that, and how can I get avoid having to create a symlink?

Thanks

Comment: Add proj to [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Python will then know where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a symlink. Django [will do all to work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/) for you in `manage.py`.

Comment: thanks.  it seems that in my settings file i had 'from proj import local_settings' and it didn't like it. Just using 'import local_settings' works.